# Execution Order in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, wit.ai

I am trying to display some data from an api withint the console, but it seems like I didn't understand how the code execution works in ES6.

```
getMovieReccomendation({context, entities}){
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var movie = firstEntityValue(entities, 'movie')
        if ('movie') {
            var movieData = omdbapicall(movie);
            console.log(movieData);
            context.movieReccomendation = 'You should see ' + movieData.Title;
            delete context.missingMovieTitle;
        } else {
            context.missingMovieTitle = true;
            delete context.movieReccomendation;
        }
        return resolve(context);
    })
}
```

};

```
function omdbapicall(movieTitle) {
console.log(movieTitle);
request('http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=' + movieTitle + '&plot=short&r=json', function (error, response, body) {
    if (error) {
        throw error;
    }
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        var apiData = JSON.parse(body);
        var movieInfo = {
            "Title": apiData.Title,
            "Plot": apiData.Plot,
            "imdbRating": apiData.imdbRating,
            "imdbVotes": apiData.imdbVotes
    };
    console.log(apiData);
    return apiData;
    }
})
```

}

The Error I get is the following :

```
Memento
undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Title' of undefined
at C:\Users\Derp\WebstormProjects\moviereccomendation\examples\quickstart.js:69:76
at Object.getMovieReccomendation (C:\Users\Derp\WebstormProjects\moviereccomendation\examples\quickstart.js:64:16)
at C:\Users\Derp\WebstormProjects\moviereccomendation\lib\wit.js:121:36
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
JSON Object returned by API
```

So I think the error is caused by the execution order, since the code tries to continue within my getMoveReccomendation Function while still executing my omdbapicall.

I think I just have to wait for the function to finish, since it logs the JSON Object after the error, but I don't know how.

Comment: Debug the value of `body`

Comment: omdbapicall is async.

Comment: As  omdbapicall is async call you are getting that error.Actually it executes your context.movieReccomendation = 'You should see ' + movieData.Title; first and then go for HTTP call.So to avoid this place your after call code in omdbapicall function itself.